# iterative program on java

Tags: java, iteration

i have this program

```
public static int p(int n, int m){
    if(n==m) return n;
    if (n<m) return p(n,m-n);
    else return p(n-m,m);


}
```

how to put this program on iterative program with while loop. 
Thanks

Comment: homework assignments which show 0 effort are likely to get downvoted

Comment: What have you tried for this problem? SO it's to solve doubts or try to solve code that you have tried before, but not for doing homework for free.

Comment: i'm beginner on java

Comment: @am9511 and we accept it. I'm also a beginner on Java. You are getting so much downvotes because you don't post the code that you have tried for. You should try before come SO some code and, if you have any doubt, ask a question here.

Answer (score 1):

This code substacts the smaller of the two inputs from the larger until they are equal. This can be done with a while loop:

```
public static int p(int n, int m){
    while (m!=n) {
        if (n<m)
            m -= n;
        else
            n -= m;
    }
    return n;
}
```